# Invalid field Gender__c for SObject Characteristics__c

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am getting above error.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="actionSupportController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            Household Name:
            <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Characteristics Information">
            Goods with Cats
            <apex:inputCheckbox/> High Need
            <apex:inputCheckbox/> Non-shedder
            <apex:inputCheckbox/> Predatory Tendencies
            <apex:inputCheckbox/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getchrc}" rerender="sblck" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputPanel id="sblck">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selctchr}" var="eachchar">
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Gender__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Height__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Name__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.pet__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Pet_Photo__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Address__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!eachchar.Status__c}" />

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:commandButton value="Request Adoption" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class actionSupportController {
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;} 
    public List<PCS_Household__c> OnlstQuery{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}      
    public string test{get;set;}

    public List<wpetwizardcontroller> chrcs{get;set;}
    public List<Characteristics__c> selctchr{get;set;}

    public List<wpetwizardcontroller> getchrc(){
        if(chrcs==null){
            chrcs=new List<wpetwizardcontroller>();
            for(Characteristics__c chrc:[SELECT ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c]){
                chrcs.add(new wpetwizardcontroller(chrc));
            }
        }
        return chrcs;
    }

    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test';        
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        OnlstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

    public Void doSearch(){
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }

    public void nullify(){
        lstQuery.clear();
    }

    public PageReference nextpage() {

        upsert OnlstQuery;

        return Page.cc;
    }

    public class wpetwizardcontroller{
        public Characteristics__c chrc{get;set;} 
        public boolean selectd{get;set;}

        //public Boolean Good_with_Cats {get; set;}
        //public Boolean HighNeed {get; set;}
        //public Boolean Non_shedder {get; set;}
        //public Boolean kid_friendly {get; set;}
        //public Boolean Predatory_Tendencies {get; set;}

        public wpetwizardcontroller(Characteristics__c chrc){
            this.chrc=chrc;
            selectd=false;
            //Good_with_Cats=false;
            //HighNeed=false;
            //Non_shedder=false;
            //kid_friendly=false;
            //Predatory_Tendencies=false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Gender__c is not a field of Characteristics__c  it is field of it's parent  use like that `eachchar.Pet_ID__r.Gender__c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
<apex:column value="{!eachchar.Gender__c}" />
```

Do this

```
<apex:column value="{!eachchar.Pet_ID__r.Gender__c}" />
```

It will solve your problem.